# get ordered quantity in magento report renderer custom

Tags: magento, renderer

I want to get the ordered quantity of a product. I can get sku, name, price, etc. But I can't get the ordered quantity.
This is what I am so far:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{ 
    $sku = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($row->getId())->getSku();
    $price = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($row->getId())->getPrice();
    $quantity = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($row->getId())->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do that :

```
$orderedQty = 0;
$report = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
->addOrderedQty() //you can also filter by date range, like ->addOrderedQty($from, $to) with proper SQL dates
->addIdFilter($row->getId())
->getFirstItem();

if ($report) {
    $orderedQty = $report->getOrderedQty();
}
```

Additionally, you might want to dive in the classes `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Sold_Collection` and `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` in which you'll find some interesting self-explanatory methods such as :

```
public function setDateRange($from, $to)
public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
public function addOrdersCount($from = '', $to = '')
```

Comment: Can I filter the quantity by the specific date of the current row?

Comment: @Tedxxxx you welcome ! :) If it answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Yes you could indeed, you just need to determine the interval you want to filter on, and how you retrieve it from your row. Also, take care the date you use is SQL compliant.

Comment: I mean I want to get the ordered quantity of a specific date individually. But currently, for example, Product A is ordered x quantity at the date 2017-07-01 and y at the date 2017-08-01. But currently my code shows on the later date 2017-08-01 x+y quantity.I want to show only the quantity of the date a product is ordered. Please help! :)

Comment: @Tedxxxx have you tried ->addOrderedQty('2017-07-01, '2017-07-01') ?

Comment: Actually I only need to add this code $orderQty=$row->getOrderedQty() to get all the orders in the current Collection. Problem solved! Thank you for your help!